# In browser Chrome method POST goes like GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

In all browser OK, but in chrome method POST goes like GET

```
   $(function() { 
           $('#login').submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if ($(this).parsley('validate')) {
                 $.ajax ({
                     type: "POST",
                      url: "user/login.php",
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                 dataType: "json",
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           location.href="pages-500.php";
                           },
                  success: function(data) {
                           if (data.status === 'OK') {
                               location.href= '';
                           }
                           else {
                              $('#error').html(data.message);
                           }
                         }
              }); } });
        });
```

result:

Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Why? In another part of frontpage site ajax work fine in chrome (send mail, contact...etc)

Answer (score 1):

problem in

```
    $(function() { 
});
```

chrome don't see ajax in this noname function
He goes to form and ask there. In form action is empty (handler) nowhere to send query
and method in form empty too, that browser sent by GET

problem solved